# How does Intel Anti-Theft work?

Tags: intel-amt

I read about it on Intel's site, it's available for those laptop that come with built in 3G support. So is that 3G device working like BIOS clock, that needs no external power normally?

What if the laptop is being powered off before you shut it down remotely ?

Comment: If I told you, I'd have to kill you.

Comment: My non-3G laptop from Asus came with this enabled in the BIOS. no mention in the manual tho. Disabled right away just to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

The Intel Anti-theft technology has several pieces to it.  At the lowest level the CPU has features that essentially destroy the laptop before sensitive data can be stolen.  If the laptop does not have a 3G support, I'm assuming this would be initiated as soon as the laptop got an Internet connection.

On top of that, the Intel anti-theft technology often includes software from Mcaffee, which can lock the computer, report it's general location, and even take screenshots with the camera.

Source: [Toms Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/vpro-anti-theft-small-business-advantage,3259-10.html)